# How to solve Project 12.15 in Walter Savitch Absolute C++ 5th Ed

Tags: c++, string, file-io, char

I have been working the Project 15 in Chapter 12 of Walter Savitch Absolute C++ (5th ed.) for a long time. The problem is at the bottom, which you can check if you are interested in my problem.

I figure out one way to solve this problem which is to read the file containing a paragraph many times and at each time, locate the keyword, the line number and the context. But it sounds to me very tedious. So I tried to read the file only twice. At the first time reading it, I locate all the keywords and line numbers. At the second time reading the file, I determine the context. But I failed.

I do not attempt to fix bugs in my code (

```
// header file for project 15
#ifndef PROJECT15_H
#define PROJECT15_H

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>

using std::ios;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::string;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::stringstream;

const int MAX_CHARACTERS = 72;
const int N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE = 2;
const int N_CHARACTERS_AFTER = 1;

namespace
{
    void sortKWIX(string** list, int size);

    void advanceChain(string chain[], string newStr);

    void printKWIX(string** list, int size, ostream& outStream);
} // namespace

namespace project15
{
    void getKWIX(string keyWords[], int size, string file, ostream& outStream);
} //namespace project15


#endif // PROJECT15_H

/******************************************************************************//******************************************************************************//******************************************************************************/


// function definitions for project 15
#include"Project15.h"

namespace
{
    void sortKWIX(string** list, int size)
    {
        string tmp;
        for (int outer = 0; outer < size - 1; outer++)
            for (int inner = outer + 1; inner < size; inner++)
                if (strcmp(list[outer][0].c_str(), list[inner][0].c_str()) > 0)
                {
                    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
                    {
                        tmp = list[outer][index];
                        list[outer][index] = list[inner][index];
                        list[inner][index] = tmp;
                    }
                }
    }

    void advanceChain(string chain[], string newStr)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE; index++)
            chain[index] = chain[index + 1];
        chain[N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE] = newStr;
    }

    void printKWIX(string** list, int size, ostream& outStream)
    {
        outStream.setf(ios::left);
        outStream.width(12);
        outStream << "KWIX Listing:\n"
            << "Keyword " << "Line Number " << "Keyword in Context\n";
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            for (int ncol = 0; ncol < 3; ncol++)
                outStream << list[index][ncol] << " ";
            outStream << endl;
        }
    }
} // namespace

namespace project15
{
    void getKWIX(string keyWords[], int size, string file, ostream& outStream)
    {
        using namespace std;
        ifstream fin(file.c_str());
        if (fin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Input file openning failed.\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        string inp;
        char next;
        int nChars = 0;
        int nline = 0;
        int position = 0;
        vector<string> keys;
        vector<int> positions;
        vector<int> nlines;
        while (fin >> inp)
        {
            position++;
            if (!fin.eof())
                fin.get(next);
            else
                next = '\0';
            // determine line number
            if ((nChars + inp.length() > MAX_CHARACTERS) || (next == '\n'))
            {
                nline++;
                nChars = inp.length();
            }
            else
                nChars += inp.length();
            if (next != '\n')
                nChars++;
            if (!fin.eof() && (fin.peek() == '\n'))
                nline++;
            // determine whether inp is a keyword
            // first, determine if the last character in inp is not an alphabet
            if (!(isalpha(inp[inp.length() - 1])))
                inp = inp.substr(0, inp.length() - 1);
            for (int index = 0; index < size;index++)
                if (inp == keyWords[index])
                {
                    keys.push_back(inp);
                    positions.push_back(position);
                    nlines.push_back(nline);
                    break;
                }
        }

        fin.close();

        // open the file for the 2nd time to get contexts
        fin.open(file.c_str());
        if (fin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Input file openning failed.\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        position = 0;
        int index = 0;
        vector<string> contexts;
        string tmp[N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE + 1];
        for (int iter = 0; iter < N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE + 1; iter++)
            tmp[iter] = "";

        while (fin >> inp)
        {
            //position++;
            advanceChain(tmp, inp);
            if (!fin.eof())
                fin.get(next);
            else
                next = '\0';

            // determine where to start to save contexts
            if (positions[index] - position <= N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE)
            {
                // determine where to start to save strings
                string str = "";
                if (positions[index] - N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE < 0)
                {
                    for (int iter = N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE - position; iter < N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE + 1; iter++)
                        str += tmp[iter];
                    position++;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int iter = N_CHARACTERS_AFTER - position + positions[index]; iter < N_CHARACTERS_AFTER + N_CHARACTERS_BEFORE + 1; iter++)
                        str += tmp[iter];
                    position++;
                }

                for (int iter = 0; iter < N_CHARACTERS_AFTER; iter++)
                {
                    if (!fin.eof())
                    {
                        fin >> inp;
                        advanceChain(tmp, inp);
                        str += inp;
                        position++;
                    }
                }
                contexts.push_back(str);
                index++;
            }
        }

        fin.close();

        // form a new list
        string** list = new string*[keys.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
            list[i] = new string[3];

        stringstream ss;
        for (int nrow = 0; nrow < keys.size(); nrow++)
        {
            list[nrow][0] = keys[nrow];
            ss.str("");
            ss << nlines[nrow];
            list[nrow][1] = ss.str();
            list[nrow][2] = contexts[nrow];
        }
        sortKWIX(list, keys.size()); 
        printKWIX(list, keys.size(), outStream);
    }
} //namespace project15
```

) right now, but I want to hear from you what kind of method you would like to use to solve this problem. Would you give me some hint?

===================================================================== Problem:

In this program you are to process text to create a KWIX table (Key Word In conteXt table). The idea is to produce a list of keywords (not programming language keywords, rather words that have important technical meaning in a discussion),then for each instance of each keyword, place the keyword, the line number of the context, and the keyword in its context in the table. There may be more than one context for a given keyword. The sequence of entries within a keyword is to be the order of occurrence in the text. For this problem, “context” is a user-selected number of words before the keyword, the keyword itself, and a user-selected number of words after the keyword. The table has an alphabetized column of keywords followed by a line number(s) where the keyword occurs, followed by a column of all contexts within which the keyword occurs. See the following example.

Hints: To get your list of keywords, you should choose and type in several paragraphs from the text, then omit from your paragraph “boring” words such as forms of the verb “to be”; pronouns such as I, me, he, she, her, you, us, them, who, which, etc. Finally, sort the keyword list and remove duplicates. The better job you do at this, the more useful output you will get.

Example: A paragraph and its KWIX Listing:

There are at least two complications when reading and writing with random access via an fstream : (1) You normally work in bytes using the typechar or arrays of char and need to handle type conversions on your own, and (2) you typically need to position a pointer (indicating where the read or write begins) before each read or write.

KWIX Listing:

Keyword Line Number Keyword in Context

access 2 with random access via

arrays 3 char or arrays of

bytes 2 work in bytes using char 3 the type
 char or

char 3 array of char and

conversions 3 handle type conversions on

The table is longer than these sample entries.

Comment: I vote to close: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions C. These are different languages (why do we have to say this so often?)

Comment: It is easier to use the `map`.